# transactional operations with paypal api

Tags: paypal

I am adding payments to our website.  I would like a way to update my database and capture a payment via paypal api within a transaction.  Does anybody know if there is any way to do this?  Perhaps a paypal callback?

Answer (score 0):

Do the capture and after that, update the database. Some minutes later you'll receive an IPN message with details about the capture and you can use it to check whether the database is updated. But don't rely on IPN only, from my experience I can say that it's not 100% reliable.  Sometimes it happens that I don't receive some of the IPNs, or they are delayed with some hours.